# Directories for uploading and downloading by SmartFTP will be empty

Tags: ftp

I am new to this forum. 
My question is this:

I have just installed SmartFTP as a trial version (version 5.0.1364.0 = 32 bit version). But the problem is that when uploading and downloading directories, the directories will be empty. All files and subdirectories in the directory will not be uploaded or downloaded just the directory itself.

I have tried to figure out if there are some settings in the software and I have also tried to find the answer by Google and Youtube but I have found nothing. Does anybody know anything about this?